# How to purge connections left open by SSH ProxyCommand?

Tags: linux, proxy, ssh, netcat

I have a webserver WWW1 and a front-facing proxy PRX. I use SSH ProxyCommand to connect to WWW1's internal IP (private IP) via PRX (private+public IP). For some connections (not all) I see a network connection left open after I'm finished. These add up!

~/.ssh/config

```
Host *
  ServerAliveInterval 5
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p

Host WWW1 WWW2 WWW3
  User foo
  ProxyCommand ssh -q -a -x PRX nc %h 22
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_foo_WWWx
```

On PRX, `lsof | grep WWW1:ssh` shows 124 open connections at the moment. On WWW1, the same command shows 243 open connections. There are similar open connections for WWW2, WWW3 etc.

WWW1 and PRX are Debian. Client connections are coming from a mix of Debian, Ubuntu and OSX10.6. I use Emacs Tramp but this has no special configuration (AFAIK) outside of my `~/.ssh/config`.

I'm concerned about running out of internal ports, and ideally I want these connections to clean themselves up without intervention. Ideally by configuring them to kill themselves off; failing that a command I can kill old processes with is fine!

Comment: One workaround *might* be to set up a cron task which kills the `nc` processes on PRX after a week ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know whether it matters but I use `nc -w 1 %h %p`

Comment: You beauty! I can't believe I waited for the same question to get a "Tumbleweed" badge on SuperUser.com before asking it here where it was answered in five minutes. Because nc usage isn't a *programming* question, right?

Comment: Nah, only [real programmers](http://www.th-soft.com/zzJargon/R.htm#Real_Programmer) know how to tunnel through proxies :)

Comment: Before I tested nc -w 3 in bash, it didn't timeout, so I thought it didn't work, but it did work in ssh proxycommand, I didn't know why yet. 
It exited, but it's very long, I wrote 3 seconds, but it exited after 2 minutes: 
# date; nc -n -w 3 192.168.3.3 22; date
Tue Jun  7 18:26:45 CST 2022
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
Tue Jun  7 18:28:45 CST 2022
ii  netcat-traditional                 1.10-40                       amd64        TCP/IP swiss army knife

Comment: date; nc -n -w 3 -q 0 -v 172.22.18.19 22; date
2022年 06月 08日 星期三 12:08:13 CST
Connection to 172.22.18.19 22 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
2022年 06月 08日 星期三 12:08:16 CST
Add '-q' to '-w', it's okay, much better. There's something to do with nc version.

Answer (score 10):

A better way would be to use the `-W` option of SSH, so you could put

```
 ProxyCommand ssh -q -a -x PRX -W %h:22
```

instead of

```
 ProxyCommand ssh -q -a -x PRX nc %h 22
```

This way you get rid of dependence on `nc` too.